# Interstitial Ads; Google Play services missing?

Tags: java, android, ads, interstitial

I'm just totally butchering how to ad interstitial ads and need help. My emulator works when I use an example interstitial program, but it doesn't work for current app I'm working on. Please help, I'm desperate at this point!!
please don't mind the excessive wall of code.

Java file (lots of extra code):

```
 public class Settings extends ActionBarActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

EditText calorieSet;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    // Defined in res/values/strings.xml
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));

    //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    //mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    calorieSet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calorieSet);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   getApplication().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String calValue = sharedPreferences.getString("calValue", null);
    calorieSet.setText( calValue );


}




public void onClick(View view) {





    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    final EditText calorieSet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calorieSet);
    String userCals= calorieSet.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("calorieSet", userCals);


    if (userCals == null || userCals.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a calorie number",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else { showInterstitial();
               // startActivity();
     }



         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   getApplication().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("calValue", calorieSet.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    startActivity(i);}



    private void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and restart the game.
    if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity();
    }
    }

    private void startActivity() {
    // Hide the retry button, load the ad, and start the timer.
    //mRetryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    //mCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     android {
     compileSdkVersion 22
     buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pjproductions.thinr"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
     }

     dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pjproductions.thinr" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />




            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />


</application>
```

logcat error:

```
        12 22:09:11.346  15622-15622/com.pjproductions.thinr W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
        05-12 22:09:11.368  15622-15622/com.pjproductions.thinr I/WebViewFactory﹕ Loading com.android.webview version 39 (1737576-x86) (code 300007)
         05-12 22:09:11.378  15622-15622/com.pjproductions.thinr I/LibraryLoader﹕ Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 6461-6462)
        05-12 22:09:11.378  15622-15622/com.pjproductions.thinr I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual version number ""
```